# How to Integrate a piece of python code in a c++,qt,vtk,itk environment in visual studio?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, qt, vtk

I have built a GUI of a dicom reader in axial,saigittal and coronal views using c++, qt,vtk and itk. Now i want to integrate a python code of dicom folder reader(i.e. replace it with existing c++ dicom folder reader) in visual studio. Is this possible??

Comment: Yes, probably...

Comment: @Scheff would like to know how it's done.

Comment: Sorry. (I couldn't resist.) Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read [SO: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutly possible.

you can use Boost.Python library that allow you to interface Pyhton and C++

see the link below for more information

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html